# Converting today's date to text string

Tags: excel, vba

I need today's date as a text string in the format of yyyymmdd.

I have the following code.

```
Newsh.Range("l2:l" & numcampaigns).Value = "=today()"
```

This file gets uploaded to a site, and won't accept if formula *=today()* is in the box.

Tried:

```
Newsh.Range("l2:l" & numcampaigns).Value = "=today()"
```

Result: shows *=today* in the textbox, and formatted as a long date. I set the column to have custom formatting of YYYYMMDD, but it still errors because of the presence of *=today* in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
    strDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    Debug.Print TypeName(strDate), strDate
```

**Output**

```
String        20230911
```

Your code is

```
strDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
Newsh.Range("l2:l" & numcampaigns).Value = strDate
```